# Pivoting in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

Can anybody tell me is there a way in elasticsearch/kibana to provide pivoting feature as in Oracle?

I want to create a report with pivoting a field with sum as aggregation.

For example : I have this schema indexed in `test-index/test-type` Doc id being `ID`.

```
ID | NAME | Code | AMT
-----------------------
1  | ABC  |   a  | 10
2  | DEF  |   c  | 20
3  | XYZ  |   a  | 30
4  | ABC  |   a  | 10
5  | ABC  |   c  | 20
6  | XYZ  |   b  | 30
7  | DEF  |   c  | 10
8  | DEF  |   a  | 20
```

I want to generate a report pivoting done like this : SUM(AMT) FOR CODE IN (a,b,c)

```
NAME | a  |  b  | c 
---------------------
ABC  | 20 |  0  | 20
DEF  | 20 |  0  | 30
XYZ  | 30 | 30  | 0
```

Can we do it using elasticsearch and reports generated in kibana? 
PS. I am new to Elasticsearch Query DSL, so it would be helpful if someone having good grasp on query DSL can help me out whether its possible in ES , or suggest me a way to do this??